# CSS - complex @media query for mobile devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I need this condition:

```
(min-width:320px AND max-width:800px) OR (min-width:801px AND orientation:portrait)
```

Tried to use parentheses like this, but it doesn't work:

```
@media screen and ((min-width:320px) and (max-width:800px)), ((min-width:801px) and (orientation:portrait))
```

I always use only widths in media queries, so I doesn't have an experience with complex queries. How can I write this?

Comment: Having `max-width` in a media query is most of the time an indication that you do something wrong. When designing a webpage you should do mobile first. And then use media queries with `min-width` to make your layout more complex. Such complex media queries lead to hard to maintain and hard to control layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excess brackets seem to mean the expressions aren't parsed correctly. I don't know why but this layout works:

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:800px), screen and (min-width:801px) and (orientation:portrait)
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:800px),
screen and (min-width:801px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Run the snippet in full screen and gradually decrease the window width.